# Hold all the symbols from a huge list?

Tags: hold, symbols

The two following codes work similarly:

```
Num = 5; 
symbols = Hold[X1, X2, X3, X4, X5];
```

or

```
Num = 5; 
Xlists= StringJoin["X", #] & /@ Array[ToString, Num];
symbols = Hold[Xlists[[1]], Xlists[[2]], Xlists[[3]], Xlists[[4]], Xlists[[5]]];
```

**Question:**

> When `Num` is large (for instance `Num=200`), **I would not like to use the stupid way**: write all the `X1, X2, ..., X200` in the `Hold[]`.
>
> I wonder whether there are something like `Hold[Xlists]` for such problem. Well, I tried different ways but failed.

Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit2:**

```
Num=5;
data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 2}};
For[ii = 1, ii <= Num, ii++,
  symbols[[{ii}]] /. _[x_] :> (x = data[[ii]])
  ];
```

I know that the `X1,X2,...X5` will have certain values such as `X1` will be `{0,0,0}`. Then it seems that I cannot get the symbol `X1` using the way `symbols[[1]]` because it will return `{0,0,0}` not `X1` (except I directly write as `X1`).

So after giving values to X1,X2,..., how can I can the it form `symbols` instead of directly using X1,X2,...

Thank you!

Comment: @xzczd, thank you for pointing out. I have modified it.

Comment: When e.g. `X1=12345`, what behavior is desired? `Hold[X1, X2, X3, X4, X5]`, or `Hold[12345, X2, X3, X4, X5]`?

Comment: @xzczd, X1 and all the Xn is a symbol which you can give values later. I think it is Hold[X1, X2, X3, X4, X5], and then give values to certain symbol. because I would like to use `DumpSave` for storing with the related symbol. Since `DumpSave` doesn't work for something like `list[[1]]`.

Comment: Then why not `Hold @@ (Symbol["X" <> ToString@#] & /@ Range[5])`?

Comment: @xzczd, oh, thank you. I don't know this way.

Comment: @xzczd, one more question: if i give values to X1,X2,... and then `symbols[[index]]` will not return the symbol X1,X2,... as I want but gives me the given values. Could you please have a look? I edit such question in the end.

Comment: @xzczd, something like "give values to variable and then get the name (or symbol) of variable" instead writing the variable itself (since there will be many variables in the form of X1, X2, X3,...)

Comment: Just make use of `OwnValues`: `Clear[X1];
symbols = {X1, X2, X3};
X1 = 123;
Hold@symbols /. OwnValues[symbols]`

Comment: @xzczd, cool but afterwards how can you pick up the symbol `X1` from`Hold[{X1, X2, X3}]`? Since I want to do something like `DumpSave[path, X1]` Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: `help = Map[Function[x, SymbolName@Unevaluated@x, HoldAll], #, {2}] &@Hold[{X1, X2, X3}];
help[[1, 1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fourth argument of `Array` as follows:

```
Array["X" <> ToString@# &, Num, 1, Hold[##] &]
```

> ```
>  Hold["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"]
> ```

```
Array[Symbol["X" <> ToString@#] &, Num, 1, Hold[##] &]
```

> ```
>  Hold[X1, X2, X3, X4, X5]
> ```

If you want to wrap each element with `Hold`:

```
Array["X" <> ToString@# &, Num, 1, Hold /@ {##} &]
```

> ```
> {Hold["X1"], Hold["X2"], Hold["X3"], Hold["X4"], Hold["X5"]}
> ```

```
Array[Symbol["X" <> ToString@#] &, Num, 1, Hold /@ {##} &]
```

> ```
> {Hold[X1], Hold[X2], Hold[X3], Hold[X4], Hold[X5]}
> ```

Comment: thank you again, kglr :) so helpful!

Comment: @Xuemei, my pleasure.

Comment: I edit one small question in the end: if i give values to X1,X2,... and then `symbols[[index]]` will not return the symbol X1,X2,... as I want but gives me the given values. Could you please have a look? Thank you very much! do you think it is possible?

Comment: hey, kglr. the Edit2 part is something like "give values to variable and then get the name (or symbol) of variable" instead writing the variable itself (since there will be many variables in the form of X1, X2, X3,...). Thank you!

Comment: @Xuemei, unfortunately I don't know the answer to your second question.

Comment: I just thought to use `Name["X*"]`. thank you anyway :)